# Creating a dynamic array of char* from a char* text using strtok_s

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, memory, char

My search here got many results, but none quite like so that I could find a solution to my problem.

I'm creating a Mathcad UserEFI DLL in C using Visual Studio 2013. I don't want to use strings, only char*.

Now, I want to emulate the console main function, which uses char* argv[] to access the parameters of a called executable. Mathcad will call the DLL with a string like "-T=3 z h 13". All I want is to parse this text into an array of char*, just like argv[] would be if I called an executable with this added parameters. I hope I expressed this in an understandable way. 
I use strtok_s to parse the text and one has to consider, that every token can have a different size.

The error must lie in the following function:

```
typedef struct tArgReturnType  {
    int ACount;
    char** Argus;
} ARGRETURN;

ARGRETURN ParseStringToArgs(char* text) {
    char *token = NULL;
    char *nextToken = NULL;
    int argCount = 0;
    char* temptext = NULL;
    strcpy(temptext, text);

    char** uebergabe = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**)); 

    token = strtok_s(temptext, " ", &nextToken); 

    while (token != NULL) {
        argCount++;
        uebergabe = (char**)realloc(uebergabe, sizeof(uebergabe)+sizeof(token));
        uebergabe[argCount - 1] = token;
        token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &nextToken);
    }
    ARGRETURN ReturnVar;
    ReturnVar.ACount = argCount;
    ReturnVar.Argus = (char**)malloc(sizeof(uebergabe));
    memcpy(ReturnVar.Argus, uebergabe, sizeof(uebergabe));
    free(uebergabe);

    return ReturnVar;
}
```

I'm sure that this is a complete mishmash of heap memory allocation failures (as indicated by the error the mathcad compiler gives me), since I modified this code multiple times while trying to find a solution. I'm just utterly confused now.

---

**Updated Code:**

```
typedef struct tArgReturnType  {
    int ACount;
    char** Argus;
} ARGRETURN;

ARGRETURN ParseStringToArgs(char* text) {
    char *token = NULL;
    char *nextToken = NULL;
    int argCount = 0;
    char* temptext = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    strcpy(temptext, text);

    char** uebergabe = malloc(sizeof(char**)); 

    token = strtok_s(temptext, " ", &nextToken); 

    while (token != NULL) {
        argCount++;
        uebergabe = (char**)realloc(uebergabe, sizeof(uebergabe)+sizeof(token));
        uebergabe[argCount - 1] = token;
        token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &nextToken);
    }
    ARGRETURN ReturnVar;
    ReturnVar.ACount = argCount;
    ReturnVar.Argus = malloc(sizeof(uebergabe));
    memcpy(ReturnVar.Argus, uebergabe, sizeof(uebergabe));
    free(uebergabe);
    free(temptext);

    return ReturnVar;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(temptext, text);` --> `temptext` has no memory allocated, `char** uebergabe = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**)); ` is wrong. It should be `char** uebergabe = malloc(sizeof(char*)); `. `ReturnVar.Argus = (char**)malloc(sizeof(uebergabe));` is wrong. It should be `ReturnVar.Argus = malloc(sizeof(*uebergabe));`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code the way you proposed (see original post), this still doesn't quite fix it. There seems to be a problem with memory allocation. Did I allocate temptext's memory right?

Comment: No. `char* temptext = malloc(sizeof(text));` should be `char* temptext = malloc(strlen(text)+1);`

Comment: Did that. The error message now reads: "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#78( at 0x0F0967D0. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer." - I strongly suspect the realloc of uebergabe to be the culprit... especially since to my knowledge CRT can only detect this errors when free()ing something, and since uebergabe is the only variable I'm free()ing it has got to do something with that, right?

Comment: Instead of char* temptext = malloc(sizeof(text));
    strcpy(temptext, text);
You can use char* temptext = text ? strdup(text) : NULL; You should also free temptext. Why do you need to copy final array? You have worng size calculation. In case of 0 argCount do you want to return Array with NULL?

Comment: I really just want ReturnVar.Argus to be identicaly to uebergabe. It's very possible that memcpy is unnecessary. Thanks for the hint about freeing temptext.

Comment: Look at my first comment carefully. Did you do the **exact** changes I told you to do? And remove all the casts from your code. You should never cast the result of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` in C. Also, `uebergabe = (char**)realloc(uebergabe, sizeof(uebergabe)+sizeof(token));` should be `uebergabe = realloc(uebergabe, (sizeof(uebergabe)/sizeof(*uebergabe))+strlen(token)+1);` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I believe I implemented your first proposed changes (see updated code), but I went with user411313's solution anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ARGRETURN ParseStringToArgs(const char* text) {
  ARGRETURN ReturnVar = { 0 };
  int n = 0;
  char temp[100];

  while (sscanf(text += n, "%99s%n", temp, &n) == 1) {
    ReturnVar.Argus = realloc(ReturnVar.Argus, ++ReturnVar.ACount*sizeof(*ReturnVar.Argus));
    strcpy(ReturnVar.Argus[ReturnVar.ACount - 1] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1), temp);
  }

  return ReturnVar;
}
```

- 'sizeof(text)' is a great mistake
- don't use ugly strtok(_s), it's not reentrant, destroys the string, ...
- use sscanf instead